# Estilo de ecuaciones en LaTeX

Tags: latex

estoy elaborando un documento en LaTeX, quiero que mis ecuaciones tengan el estilo de la primera ecuación mostrada en la imagen, pero tienen el estilo de la segunda ecuación. ¿Cómo logro tener el estilo de la primera ecuación? ¿Tengo que agregar o eliminar algún paquete?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución a esto, desactivando el paquete euler del prólogo de mi documento.

Answer (score 0):

parece que la que quieres está inclinada o en cursiva, prueba con esto:
\textit{Texto escrito en cursiva} ó esto:\textsl{Texto roman de estilo inclinado}

Comment: Emplee ambas cosas y ninguna de las dos es.

Answer (score 0):

según leo [acá](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_fonts): hay que utilizar otro tipo de fuente, en este enlace usan:

```
\mathit{3x^2 \in R \subset Q} \\
```

mostrandose como:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]